# YACC - strlen of $1 is 0 although string is there

Tags: bison, yacc

I am having a strange error in my program

The structure of my YYSTYPE is

```
%union
{
        char *text;
        node *n;
}
%token <text> NUMBER
```

and the grammar rule is

```
P:
        NUMBER
        {
                cout<<"$1 : "<<$1<<endl;
                int i = 0;
                while($1[i])
                {
                        cout<<"char : "<<$1[i++]<<endl;
                }
                $<n>$->left = $<n>$->right = NULL;
                char *test1 = new char[strlen($1)];
                strcpy(test1, $1);
                cout<<"len : "<<strlen($1)<<"test1 : "<<test1<<endl;
                char *lolz = strdup($1);
                cout<<"dup : "<<((uint64_t)lolz)<<' '<<((int)lolz[1])<<" : dup"<<endl;
                $<n>$->data = string($1);
                cout<<"nd : "<<$<n>$->data<<endl;
                print_tree($<n>$);
        }
        ;
```

I can print the contents of $1, but when I do strlen($1), it returns 0 length
This is causing the strdup and string initialisation to fail.

Output:

```
$1 : 65301
char : 6
char : 5
char : 3
char : 0
char : 1
len : 0test1 :
dup : 26935504 0 : dup
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute:

```
$<n>$->left = $<n>$->right = NULL;
```

what do you suppose the value of `$<n>$` is? Have you assigned it to the address of a `node` object?

To save you some time: you haven't assigned it so you could think of it as an uninitialised pointer; dereferencing an uninitialised pointer is Undefined Behaviour and that corresponds to what you see.

But that analysis is not quite accurate.

The bison-generated parser initialises `$$` to `$1` prior to executing the action. In this case, `$1` is a union whose `text` member has been assigned to, so using the `n` member is (a different) UB. The result is the same but in common compilers it is more predictable: I suppose that the `left` element of a `node` is at offset 0, so the assignment above overwrites the first 16 bytes of the character string with zeros (8 if you have a 32-bit architecture). That's likely a buffer overrun, but if it doesn't segfault, the end result is that the first byte of `$1` is 0, hence the return value of `strlen`. (When you try to use the `data` element, it does segfault, apparently, presumably because that is not an initialised `std::string`. Using a zero-length C-string would not be a problem either for `strdup` or the `std::string` constructor.)

Moral: never assign through a pointer if you don't know what it points to.

---

By the way, the `strcpy` to test1 is a buffer overrun of one byte. You seem to have gotten away with it this time but it's a bad habit.